# COMPARE 2 ITEM IN 2 ARRAY

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to run a condition to check 2 items in 2 arrays. I pull data from a Spreasheet and copy if condition is OK.

for example I want to compare 2 cells in spreadsheet and copy the data in the high cell and update the low data in the second cell, I am new to coding can I get advice please.

```
function copyRANGEHIGH() { 
  var NEWHIGH = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INDEX-RANGE");
  var OLDHIGH = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INDEX-RANGE");  

  var VALNEWHIGH1 = NEWHIGH.getRange("U4").getValues(); //DIA
  var VALOLDHIGH1 = OLDHIGH.getRange("P5").getValues(); 

  var VALNEWHIGH2 = NEWHIGH.getRange("U22").getValues();//SPY
  var VALOLDHIGH2 = OLDHIGH.getRange("P23").getValues();

  var VALNEWHIGH3 = NEWHIGH.getRange("U39").getValues();//IWM
  var VALOLDHIGH3 = OLDHIGH.getRange("P40").getValues();

  var arr1=[VALNEWHIGH1,VALNEWHIGH2,VALNEWHIGH3];
  var arr2=[VALOLDHIGH1,VALOLDHIGH2,VALOLDHIGH3];


  for (var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
  //  Browser.msgBox(arr1[i])
     if ( arr1[i] > arr2[j] ) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete but taking those two arrays, looping over them and checking if one is greater than the other can be done like this.

```
var arr1=[VALNEWHIGH1, VALNEWHIGH2, VALNEWHIGH3];
var arr2=[VALOLDHIGH1, VALOLDHIGH2, VALOLDHIGH3];

//You only need one loop, the two arrays are the same length, 
//as long as the items you want to complare are at the same position 
//in each array this will work.

for( var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++ ) {  
   if( parseFloat(arr1[i]) > parseFloat(arr2[i]) ) { //parseFloat() converts the values to floating point numbers (decimals)
       //Value in array 1 is higher
       //Do something else here.
   }
}
```

Some extra code can be added to make converting the values to numbers safer, in case you get an unexpected value that cannot be converted to a number, but the above code should be enough to give you an idea of where to go from here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i try to add to do something Browser.msgBox(arr1[i])}  but it not show the box . iam using 2 decimal number (stock price) like 182.16 > 181.30 and then copy the high value

Comment: I've amended the answer to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` as this converts them to floating point numbers (decimals). I'm not entirely sure why your msgBox doesn't work. that may be something to do with the google-apps-script. Are you sure the `Browser.` is needed?

Comment: it works but only if the condition works in the first item in the array/ and it dont go to the other item in the array/need something like for each item to run the check. thanks for advice!!!!!

Comment: If the `if` statement doesn't run use a msgBox outside of this. log out all the values in the loop so you can check everything is as expected

Comment: works OK!!!!!!! i change to parseFloat() instead of parseInt() and it works, thanks !!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept this answer if you feel that is has solved your problem adequately (big tick next to this answer)

Comment: what left to run the code is to copy the data to the cell if the condition meet (VALNEWHIGH3 > VALOLDHIGH3){
NEWHIGH.getRange("U39").copyTo(OLDHIGH.getRange("P40"),{contentsOnly:true}) any ide for this one ?